# Football: running onto a through ball

Tags: terminologie, sport

This is about football.

"Once again, Jon Paice opened the scoring for Chelsea, running onto a through ball."

> Une fois encore, Jon Paice ouvrit le score pour Chelsea, en reprenant en pleine course une passe en profondeur.

Is this a good way to say "running onto"?

Comment: I can't find a better way to phrase it.

Comment: Bien ficelé à mon avis. J'ai pensé à un truc avec _à la volée_ mais je ne connais pas assez ce sport pour dire si ça cadrerait. C'est fort intéressant ce _running + onto_. _Courir dans_ quelque chose serait sans doute perçu comme _foncer dans_ qqc, _courir de_ quelque chose, se sauver ?! Il faut plutôt transformer ces prépositions en verbe en français ici, comme dans cette traduction vraiment éclairée, à mon avis.

Comment: In France, we take out the "en" after the comma

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

Encore une fois, Jon Paice ouvre le score pour Chelsea en prenant dans sa course une balle en profondeur.

(using the present tense as is often done in french for historical events)